# How can I override the react-phone-number-input style?

Tags: react-native

How can I override the style of the react-phone-number-input component using [react-native-phone-number-input](https://github.com/garganurag893/react-native-phone-number-input)?

I tried `containerStyle` to edit the container style:

```javascript
<PhoneInput
    containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}
    onChange={value => updateFormData('phoneNumber', value)}
    defaultValue={defaultValue}
    placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
    defaultCode="US"
    keyboardType="phone-pad"
    withDarkTheme
    withShadow
    autoFocus/>
```

But how can I edit the input style with the follow style?

```css
labelStyle: {
  fontFamily: 'calibri',
  color: '#FFF',
  fontSize: Fonts.sizes.title2
},
textInputStyle: {
  color: '#FFF',
  fontFamily: 'calibri',
  fontSize: Fonts.sizes.header,
  borderBottomWidth: 1,
  borderBottomColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)',
  marginBottom: 20,
},
```

[image: Phone input]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the inputStyle props:

```
<PhoneInput
      containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}
      onChange={value => updateFormData('phoneNumber', value)}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
      defaultCode="US"
      keyboardType="phone-pad"
      withDarkTheme
      withShadow
      autoFocus
      textInputStyle={textInputStyle }
    />
```

Comment: i already tried it but id doesn't seems to work. it works only with `containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}`

Comment: it is working in your sandbox. see attached image.

Comment: you won't see the text if you were to set color as '#fff', that will be white text on white background

Comment: it's not working i don't know why. i'm using react native

Comment: i'm using this lib https://github.com/garganurag893/react-native-phone-number-input

Comment: right. don't know why it showed me another package. I've updated the answer with textInputStyle

Comment: Yes, thanks i needed to use `textInputStyle`

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to change the color of the `placeholder`? i used the props `placeholderTextColor="white"` and i tried also `textContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'black', color:'white'}}` but it didn't work

Comment: try codeTextStyle={{  your style codes }}

Answer (score 0):

Use this one as per required:

According to *[React Phone Input 2, *Style*](https://github.com/bl00mber/react-phone-input-2#style)*, you can pass in class names and inline styles as props to each of the elements. It would look something like:

```
<PhoneInput
  ...
  containerClass="my-container-class"
  inputClass="my-input-class"
  containerStyle={{
    border: "10px solid black"
  }}
  inputStyle={{
    background: "lightblue"
  }}
/>
```

Here is my *[App.tsx](https://github.com/garganurag893/react-native-phone-number-input/blob/master/example/App.tsx)*.

**react-native**

*[React Native Phone Input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-phone-input)*

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial its not wrong package I have used in so many places , Check example and demo as per required

Comment: please read question. it's react native, not reactjs

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial So <PhoneInput its related with react native not more difference b/w my answers and given answers

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial So <PhoneInput  related with containerStyle So what is main difference not big difference exist

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Do u know about SOLID architecture its same for each coding those are exist in any application

Comment: did you check react native phone input package to see if props exist? and do u understand the very basic of react native, where they do not use html tags like <ul><li> per rendered by react-phone-input-2 .

Comment: Check my examples react-native

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Yes its true check my last link its related with native and its simple we need to npm i react-native-phone-number-input --save Check my last link

Comment: in ur example does it have inputStyle?

Comment: it really works!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This can really help!

```
<PhoneInput
    ref={this.phoneInput}
    defaultValue={this.state.value}
    defaultCode="FR"
    onChangeText={(text) => {
        thenter code hereis.state.value===text;
    }}
    onChangeFormattedText={(text) => {
        this.state.formattedValue===text;
    }}
    withDarkTheme
    withShadow
    keyboardType="phone-pad"
    containerStyle={{borderRadius:20,backgroundColor: '#463859',}}
    textInputStyle={{color:"#ffffff"}}
    codeTextStyle={{color:"#ffffff"}}
    flagButtonStyle={{color:"#ffffff"}}
    textContainerStyle=`enter code here`{{backgroundColor:'#463859',borderRadius:20,color:"#ffffff",padding:0}}
    placeholder="Numéro de téléphone"
    phoneInputContainer={true}
    textInputProps={{placeholderTextColor:"#ffffff"}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I figured the `textInputStyle` property has a padding which hides the text input when I give its container a fixed height.

```
textInputStyle:{
    padding: 0
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
textInputStyle={{fontSize:height/60}}
```

check it it works for me .

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.